# How do larger critical threat ranges work?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, critical-hit

When a weapon has a greater critical range than a natural 20, how do the additional critical numbers work? A natural 20 is always a hit (not counting things like concealment). Do the additional numbers also say it's an automatic hit? I know they don't auto-confirm when the dice roll plus the attack mods don't equal the AC, but I don't know about the initial attack roll.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Only a natural 20 is an automatic hit.**  Expanded critical threat ranges give the attack more chances to critical, but only a natural 20 automatically hits.

[PFSRD:](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Critical-Hits)

> **Increased Threat Range**
>
> Sometimes your threat range is greater than 20. That is, you can score a threat on a lower number. In such cases, a roll of lower than 20 is not an automatic hit. Any attack roll that doesn't result in a hit is not a threat.

In summary, if you're using a 19-20/x2 weapon and roll a 19 that doesn't hit the target's AC, you simply miss. There is no confirmation roll. Another, more likely, example is rolling 15 on an 18-20/x2 with Improved Critical.